# 'python -m django' gives conflicting messages in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I created a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 workoutpy2.7
```

I'm working on a workout diary web app, hence that name.
Then I installed django nonrel in it:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
```

and then djangotoolbox for django nonrel:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox
```

and then the mongodb engine:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
```

I then assumed that django was installed in my virtualenv. So I typed:

```
python -m django
```

and got the following output:

```
/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workoutpy2.7/bin/python: No module named django.__main__; 'django' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

What does this mean? For the record, the same thing happens with ANY package I install in this way. Just have a look at this:

```
(workoutpy2.7) Sahands-MacBook-Pro:workoutpy2.7 sahandzarrinkoub$ pip install pymongo
Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages
(workoutpy2.7) Sahands-MacBook-Pro:workoutpy2.7 sahandzarrinkoub$ python -m pymongo
/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workoutpy2.7/bin/python: No module named pymongo.__main__; 'pymongo' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Thankful for any help.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you do `python -m django` or `python -m pymongo`?  These libraries have websites with documentation and lots of examples of how they can be used to build software.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to tell me. I'm a beginner doing my first django app and I've been struggling with this all day, trying different things in order to get django working with mongodb. A more helpful answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @Sandi why did you try to run that command? What documentation/instructions are you following?

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude. Calling `python -m [module]` is not something that works with all python packages. Most libraries must be imported into a python program that you write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-m` option to `python` allows you to (try to) run a module/package. From the docs:

> **`-m <module-name>`**
>
> Search `sys.path` for the named module and execute its contents as the `__main__` module.
>
> Since the argument is a *module* name, you must not give a file
>   extension (`.py`). The module name should be a valid absolute Python
>   module name, but the implementation may not always enforce this (e.g.
>   it may allow you to use a name that includes a hyphen).
>
> Package names (including namespace packages) are also permitted. When
>   a package name is supplied instead of a normal module, the interpreter
>   will execute `<pkg>.__main__` as the main module. This behaviour is
>   deliberately similar to the handling of directories and zipfiles that
>   are passed to the interpreter as the script argument.

So, the thing following `-m` needs to support being run by defining a `__main__`, which is why `python -m pymongo` then states "`No module named pymongo.__main__`".

---

For the case of Django, or specifically, `django-nonrel`: It looks like `django-nonrel` hasn't been updated in years, and the most recent branch looks like a fork of Django 1.7. Django proper added `django.__main__` in 1.9, so that's why the docs you're reading are misleading you. You *might* be able to use the [Django 1.7 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/), but a NoSQL database might heavily affect the models and queries, so using the tutorial provided by the nonrel project (if it does) would be preferred.

Comment: Why then, does the official django tutorial state that I should verify my version of django with the command `python -m django --version`? This returns: `/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workoutpy2.7/bin/python: No module named django.__main__; 'django' is a package and cannot be directly executed`

Comment: Is it because django nonrel does not support being run this way where as the official django version does?

Comment: @Sandi what version of Django is installed? Check with `pip freeze | grep django`...  Oh. `django-nonrel` looks *very* old, so the current docs won't apply.

Comment: The output is `django-mongodb-engine==0.6.0
djangotoolbox==1.8.0`.

Comment: Yeah, it looks old indeed! I wonder, is there a better way of using a nosql database with Django? I haven't been successful in finding one.

Comment: @Sandi I wouldn't recommend it, but instead maybe use Flask or something. If you want to, I'd suggest to use normal Django, but don't use its ORM at all.